# MariaDB is not inserting a row when strict mode is off and column is NOT NULL and no default. Why?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I am on Windows 10, running XAMPP with MariaDB 10.1.21

I have a table with 2 columns. `col2` is NOT NULL and no default

I have 2 SQL statements

1.
`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (2, '')`

2.
`INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (2)`

For case 1 I get the following response in PHPMyAdmin:

> 1 row inserted. [br] Inserted row id: 3 (Query took 0.0541 seconds.)

For case 2 I get

> 0 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0018 seconds.)

So it fails silently. BUT on MySQL 5.6 on Linux the insert succeeds.

Additional info:

`SQL_MODE=''` (I've tried playing around with different modes. My understanding is that this setting means that STRICT mode is off.)

Why does this fail 'silently' in `XAMPP/Windows/MariaDB` but succeeds on `Linux/MySQL`? The Linux system has been running for years, the Windows system is being set up for the first time.

Comment: Please use the mysql command line tool to test the same thing.  Immediately after each `INSERT`, do `SHOW WARNINGS;`.  Also do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';` to verify what it got set to.